# Migrating Struts 1 to Struts 2

Tags: java, struts

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE web-app
  PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
  "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app id="WebApp_1163995580031">
  <display-name>Service Account Management</display-name>
  <distributable />
  <!--<login-config>
      <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
      <realm-name>MyDomainRealm</realm-name>
   </login-config>     -->
  <filter>
        <filter-name>ParamFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.xxxxx.pcb.sam.filter.ParamFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>excludeParams</param-name>
            <param-value>(.*\.|^|.*|\[('|"))(c|C)lass(\.|('|")]|\[).*</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>blockRequestParams</param-name>
            <param-value>(allowstaticmethodaccess|processbuilder|java.io)</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

      <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ParamFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <display-name>AuthenticationFilter</display-name>
    <filter-class>com.xxxx.um.filter.CommonAuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/Welcome.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/xxxx.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/aaaaa.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping> 

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/bbbbb.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/yyyyy.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/xxxxxAccount.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping> 

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/xxxxpteUser.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/xxxx1.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/xxxxx2.jsp</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/xxxx4.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/xxxx5.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/xxxxx6.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/xxxxx7.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/xxxxx8.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/xxxxxx9.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/xxxxx10.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>


  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/xxxxx01.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/xxxx02.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>


  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/xxxxxx03.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/xxxxxx04.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>


  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/xxxxx05.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/xxxxxx06.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/xxxxxx07.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/xxxxxx08.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/xxxxxx08.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>


  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/xxxxxx09.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/xcxcxcx1.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/xcxcxcxc02.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/DeleteContact.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/cddcddc1.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/xaxaaxa1.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/xssds12.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/xxxxx13.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/xxxxx14.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/xxxxx14.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/xxxxx15.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/xxxxx16.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>


  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/xxxxx17.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

   <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/axsadasd18.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>


  <!-- Standard Action Servlet Configuration (with debugging) -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>config</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
         <param-name>chainConfig</param-name>
         <param-value>org/apache/struts/tiles/chain-config.xml</param-value>
     </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>debug</param-name>
      <param-value>2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>detail</param-name>
      <param-value>2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>InitServlet</servlet-name>
        <display-name>InitServlet</display-name>
        <servlet-class>com.xxxx.pcb.sam.common.InitServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>inifile</param-name>
            <param-value>com.singtel.pcb.sam.resouces/application.properties</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>log4j-inifile</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/classes/com/singtel/pcb/sam/resources/logger.properties</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

  <!-- Standard Action Servlet Mapping -->
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


  <!-- The Usual Welcome File List -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>


  <!-- Struts Tag Library Descriptors -->
  <taglib>
    <taglib-uri>/tags/struts-bean</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld</taglib-location>
  </taglib>

  <taglib>
    <taglib-uri>/tags/struts-html</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld</taglib-location>
  </taglib>

  <taglib>
    <taglib-uri>/tags/struts-logic</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld</taglib-location>
  </taglib>

  <taglib>
    <taglib-uri>/tags/struts-nested</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-nested.tld</taglib-location>
  </taglib>

  <taglib>
    <taglib-uri>/tags/struts-tiles</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-tiles.tld</taglib-location>
  </taglib>
  <resource-ref id="ResourceRef_1163995580093">
    <description></description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/xxxx</res-ref-name>
    <jndi-name>java:/jdbc/xxxx</jndi-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Application</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>

  <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/404.html</location>
  </error-page>


</web-app>
```

this is my Struts1.3 version web.xml file, now i am migrating to Struts2 version 
can you please help me how to migrate the Struts1 to Struts2 am new to Struts
How to Upgrade web.xml file from Struts1 to Struts2

Comment: I worked with Struts 1 a loooong time ago, so I am by no means an expert. But isn't Struts 2 completely remade?

Answer (score 2):

You are going to have more differences than just the boot-strapping in the web.xml file.  Here is an article that covers a lot of the differences, including the web.xml for both 1 and 2:

http://www.developer.com/design/article.php/3709901/Comparing-the-Struts-1-and-Struts-2-Web-Application-Frameworks.htm

Comment: I know this url but my question is different .thanks for giving information